# unexpected input in "%load_ext rpy2.ipython" in R - ipython

Tags: r, ipython, rpy2, r-package

I am new to R and trying to execute the code in this [***site***](https://www.r-bloggers.com/student-performance-indicators/) but unfortunately, I am experiencing this error **"Error: unexpected input in "%load_ext rpy2.ipython""** when entering **"%load_ext rpy2.ipython"** in the R console and I tried searching google for answers but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`rpy2.ipython` is an extension for [ipython](http://ipython.org/), and [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org), when you use the IPython kernel.  Not for R. What you linked to is using IPython and calling into R from IPython, not calling in Python from within R. Not sure why they do that in what you linked, from a quick read they should use a R kernel, which would work without saying `%%R` each time.

So you should be able to reproduce what's there by not loading the rpy2 magic, skipping the `%%R` prefixes.

If you want to reproduce exactly you will need to install IPython/jupyter and run the code from the Python console.